# How to refere to previously found column VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a code in VBA that find a column with a specific name and then it makes operations with it. So I have the following code:

```
Dim arr     As Variant
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    arr = .Range(.Cells(3, control2), .Cells(3, .Column(control2).Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

The contrlo2 variable is the column in question. I want the code to take all values in this column until the end. However this does not work. I receive a syntaxis error.

Comment: Change `.Cells(3, .Column(control2).Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row` to `.Cells(.Rows.Count, control2).End(xlUp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the last cell in column `control2` with
`.Cells(3, .Column(control2).Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row`.

Inside the brackets you have 2 parameters:

- 3 - indicating the row number, so you need to change it to the last row in `control2` columns, do that by `.Cells(.Rows.Count, control2).End(xlUp).Row`.
- `.Column(control2).Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row` - indicating the column number, so here you need to just use `control2`.

I've added the `Application.Transpose` if you want your array `arr` to be 1-dimension (If you want to have it as 2-dimensional array then just remove it).

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(3, control2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, control2).End(xlUp).Row, control2)))
End With
```